# List in list becames empty when i clear temporary list which i added inside [Java]

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
java.util.List<java.util.List<String>> statuses = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
java.util.List<String> temp = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("yoi :" + temp.size());
statuses.add(temp);
System.out.println("warui :" + statuses.get(0).size());
temp.clear();
System.out.println("kirai :" + statuses.get(0).size());
```

Console output:

```
yoi :31
warui :31
kirai :0
```

Why on earth list inside other list becames empty when I clear temporary list that I used to insert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding a reference to a `List` to your `statuses` `List`, which means `statuses` holds a reference to the same `List` referenced by `temp`.

You should create a copy of `temp` before adding it to the `List`:

```
statuses.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
```

Now clearing `temp` won't affect `statuses`.

Comment: Oh I never dealt with list nested inside other lists, I thought it passes value and not reference. thanks it worked! ^^

Comment: @Haruki it passes a value, but that value is a reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you put `temp` into `statuses`, there will *not* be a copy made of `temp`, but only the reference will be set.

So either working with `temp` directly or working with `statuses.get(0)` will always return you the same instance. Every modification is on the same object.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually displaying the size of temp in your 3rd println.
Try

```
System.out.println("kirai :" + statuses.size());
```

Comment: I understand now that it uses temp by reference, but I dont use:
statuses.size() instead because I want to check size of inserted list inside and not an amount of lists in statuses.

Comment: oh sorry, passig parameters by reference is so obvious to me that I did not realize it was your problem, sorry :)

Comment: It is no problem, I fixed it :)